# System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object

Tags: c#, winforms

Trying to get the value of the selected object in a combobox (dropdown list)
Getting this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,schoolstuff.Employee]'
>   to type 'schoolstuff.Employee'.'

I tried to find a "Value" for the cboEmployees.SelectedItem but it doesn't seem like there is any..

```cs
employees[employee.Name] = employee;

cboEmployees.DataSource = new BindingSource(employees, null);
cboEmployees.DisplayMember = "Key";
cboEmployees.ValueMember = "Value";

private void cboEmployees_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cboEmployees.SelectedItem == null) return;

    var employee = (Employee)cboEmployees.SelectedItem;

    if(employee != null)
        txtName.Text = employee.Name;
}
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman yeah, had just spotted & fixed. Whoops!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SelectedItem` isn't an `Employee`.

Either use `SelectedValue`

```cs
var employee = (Employee)cboEmployees.SelectedValue;
```

Or cast to `KeyValuePair<string, Employee>`

```cs
var kvp = (KeyValuePair<string, Employee>)cboEmployees.SelectedItem;
var employee = kvp.Value;
```

Comment: @Krystian There are two options here. Which? And what is the full error (with the relevant types)?

Answer (score 1):

`cboEmployees.SelectedItem` is a `KeyvaluePair<K,V>`.

So you cannot cast it like this: `(Employee)cboEmployees.SelectedItem`

This ought to work:

```
var employee = ((KeyValuePair<string,Employee>)cboEmployees.SelectedItem).Value;
```

Or you could use SelectedValue instead:

```
    if (cboEmployees.SelectedValue == null) return;
    var employee = (Employee)cboEmployees.SelectedValue;
```